# Fazer a DIV crescer de acordo com o conteúdo

Tags: html, css

```css
.box {
height: 42px;
width: 800px;
background: aliceblue;
}
.inside-box {
height: 42px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
}
.icon-box {
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
background: url('https://i.ibb.co/31yyBQv/download-icon.png') center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="inside-box">
<div class="icon-box"></div>
<a href="#">Fazer Download</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para a DIV de (.inside-box) fique no limite do texto de "Fazer Download", sem que ela herde a largura da DIV pai (.box). Se alguém tiver uma solução eu agradeço!

Comment: use medidas relativas em %

Comment: o problema não é o tamanho, ela herda a largura da DIV com a classe "box", eu quero que ela fique com a largura limitada ao texto ou link "Fazer Download"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc tem que colocar na dive de dentro um `width`, mas que esse `width` seja "flexivel", uma das opções é colocar `width: max-content;` eu adicionei uma borda na div apenas para que vc veja que ela ocupa apenas a largura do próprio conteúdo, e não a largura do Pai

```css
.box {
height: 42px;
width: 800px;
background: aliceblue;
}
.inside-box {
height: 42px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
margin: auto;
border: 1px solid;
width: max-content;
}
.icon-box {
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
background: url('https://i.ibb.co/31yyBQv/download-icon.png') center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="inside-box">
    <div class="icon-box"></div>
    <a href="#">Fazer Download</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="inside-box">
    <div class="icon-box"></div>
    <a href="#">Fazer Download agora, clique aqui</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obg. mano, salvou minha vida!

Comment: @BrunoB.Coelho dmr, fico feliz em ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Aqui é seu código HTML arrumado, estava com uma div a mais.

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="inside-box">
    <div class="icon-box"></div>
    <a href="#">Fazer Download</a>
</div>
</div>
```

```
.box {
height: 42px;
width: 800px;

}
.inside-box {
height: 42px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
width:150px;
background: aliceblue;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto
}
.icon-box {
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
background: url('https://i.ibb.co/31yyBQv/download-icon.png') center no-repeat;
}
```

Pelo que eu entendi é isso:
Coloquei um tamanho fixo para o ' Fazer Download ', centralizei, e o background, coloquei dentro do mesmo.